# Axioms in Gödel's ontological proof are inconsistent?

Tags: logic, philosophy, fake-proofs, modal-logic, higher-order-logic

So, my problem is with Axiom 5 of the proof, where Gödel considers necessary existence as a property. However, by his own definition, a 'property' applies to objects including those whose necessary existence has not even been proven, as can be inferred from Theorem 1. This, to me, seems like the perfect example of question begging, and if such logic is to be used on other examples, the conclusions may be contradictory. For example, I can prove that a Godlike object doesn't exist using the same logic and assuming Gödel's axioms:

1. $Df. 1:A_φ(x)⇔(◇∃x⇒(◻∃x∧φ(x)))$
2. $Ax. 1:(P(φ)∧◻∀x(φ(x)⇒ψ(x)))⇒P(ψ)$
3. $Ax. 2:P(¬φ)⇔¬P(φ)$
4. $Th. 1:P(φ)⇒◇∃x(φ(x))$
5. $Ax. 3:P(◇∃x⇒◻∃x)$
6. $Th. 2:∀φ(P(φ)⇒◻∃x(A_φ(x))$

Ax.3 is inferred from Gödel's fifth axiom, where necessary existence is a positive property. From here, I can conclude that any positive property that one can think of exists. For example, if being a unicorn is a positive property (which it is) then invisible flying unicorns also exist (because God is also flying and invisible, so these are positive properties).

Note that I didn't, in any way, deviate from the axioms in Gödel's original theorem, and I didn't add any extra ones.

Obviously, though, it is very unlikely that I've just proven Gödel's proof to be wrong, so my 'theorem' must be wrong. However, I've followed through each of the steps in my 'proof' many times over and didn't manage to find any deviation from Gödel's axioms either time. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You already asked this question and then it got deleted.

Comment: @AnonymousI I did. But no one answered it because I introduced the question with a rant. I still wanted to get an answer, so I asked it again but without the rant.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on which axioms/rules you are assuming?

Comment: @Nagase I said it: the exact same axioms as Godel used in his proof. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof

Comment: Can you list them on your post?

Comment: @Nagase Edited.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by the $\exists$ symbol; are you using it *both* as the existential quantifier *and* the existence predicate? Is the existence predicate primitive or defined in the usual way as $Ex =_{df} \exists y (y=x)$?

Comment: Also, aren't there any restraints on $\phi$ in Theorem 1? I mean, if it's indeed for any $\phi$, why can't I instantiate $\phi$ to, say, $\psi(x) \wedge \neg \psi(x)$ to get a contradiction?

Comment: @Nagase Yeah, I used it as both. I should have clarified that.

Comment: @Nagase Well, I'd suspect the property $ψ(x)∧¬ψ(x)$ doesn't exist in the first place since it is self-contradictory. If not then I must be hugely misinterpreting something. Basically, Th.1 works by vacuous truth. Are there any constraints? I didn't think so, but, perhaps, I am wrong.

Comment: By the way, I checked the link you gave me and your axioms are different. For example, Axiom 1 of the link has a universal quantification, whereas yours has an existential. Moreover, the crucial Theorem 1 states that, if $\phi$ is a *positive* property, then possibly there is something that satisfies it. This is relevant because your $A(x)$ (which is not clear to me---why the extra right conjunct? And what are those existential assumptions doing there?) is plausibly not a positive property.

Comment: Oh, and Axiom 2 should be $\neg p(\phi) \iff p(\neg \phi)$ ($\phi$ is not a positive property iff its negation is). This is needed to get Theorem 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67781/discussion-between-max-and-nagase).

Comment: Th.1 doesn't follow from the axioms that precede it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass This was actually one of the other questions I wanted to ask. According to my reasoning, it does. I'm posting a question about it right now.

Comment: No, there are interpretations in which Ax1 and Ax2 are true and Th1 is false. For example, let $P(\varphi)$ mean $\phi(\text{Max})$, observe that Ax1 and Ax2 are both true for this meaning of $P$, and use Th1 to infer the existence of unicorns.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I didn't get your particular example, but I did get why I was wrong. Either way, the existence of unicorns can be inferred even without this fallacy. I edited the question to show how (which was actually my original phrasing of the question).

Comment: About your edit: If (what you call) Axiom 3 is derivable from the rest, then it should be a theorem, not an axiom. And I'd like to see a formal derivation of it, in any case (and I found the unicorn example from the edit unconvincing: what Theorem 1 says is that if being a flying unicorn is a positive property, then possibly there are flying unicorns; it says nothing about there actually being flying unicorns). Also, I found Theorem 2 incomprehensible.

Comment: @Nagase Axiom 3 is not formally derivable; it is an axiom that Godel used in his proof. His said that necessary existence was a positive property; therefore, existing necessarily rather than possibly is positive. Theorem 2 says that whatever B(x) is, if it's positive then it exists. I realised it was badly formulated. I'm reformulating it now to make it clearer. It is from Theorem 2 that I know that unicorns actually exist.

Comment: If Axiom 3 is not formally derivable, then why did you say that it is "inferred from Gödel's fifth axiom"? And if it is an extra axiom, not formally derivable from the others, then the edited question is about this new set of axioms, not Gödel's original one. As for Theorem 2, (i) the $B=\varphi$ clause seems irrelevant (quantify directly over $\varphi$), and (ii) you need to formally derive it from the rest. As it is, I have yet to see this derivation.

Comment: In any case, all these reformulations seem rather distant from your original question, which seemed to involve some confusion regarding Theorem 1. If you have *other* questions, I'd recommend asking them separately, instead of repeatedly editing this one.

Comment: @Nagase because Axiom 3 is basically Axiom 5 from Godel's proof. Okay, if you want formal proof, here it is: $P(\square \exists x) \rightarrow P(◇∃x⇒◻∃x)$. Theorem 2 IS derived from the rest. If B is positive and ◻∃x is positive then A(x) is positive, too - as it means it is composed of two positive properties; If something is composed of two positive properties, it must itself be positive, as shown in Godel's definition of G(x) and the axiom that it's positive. Anything positive exists possibly, so A(x) exists possibly. But, from df. 1, that implies it exists necessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Theorem 1 of your link actually states: $P(\phi) \implies \Diamond \exists x \phi(x)$, i.e. if $\phi$ is a positive property, then possibly there is something that instantiates it. Given this, Gödel needs an explicit axiom stating that being god-like is a positive property (Axiom 3 in your link: $P(G)$). So, in order for *your* proof to go through by use of Theorem 1, you'll need an analogous Axiom 3$'$, stating that $A(x)$ is a positive property. But then: (i) you'll have introduced an extra axiom, extraneous to Gödel's own axioms, and (ii) this axiom is not very plausible. So there is no contradiction among Gödel's *own* axioms.

Comment: 3 years later, having revisited this question, I see that there is actually no way around it. Godel's sneaky omission of the axiom $P(ϕ)∧P(ψ)⇒P(ϕ∧ψ)$ guarantees that there no obvious logical inconsistencies in his proof, even though, philosophically, this axiom was all but presumed, given that he defined the property $G$, which is positive, as the combination of all positive properties, making the possibility of other combinations of positive properties themselves being negative arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

I havent read too far into it, but i think these authors embedded the higher order modal argument into higher order logic, and proved their embedding is consistent:
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/cbenzmueller/papers/C40.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiciojM14_XAhVDRCYKHVc1CpwQFghYMAQ&usg=AOvVaw0iNVCeRqSVtD-hbE4IoPjn

However, the same authors were able to put the original argument into an extremely novel higher order modal logic prover, and they found an inconsistency that had never before appeared in the literature: 
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/16/Papers/137.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiIu4yg2o_XAhUGJiYKHSTZANAQFghsMAY&usg=AOvVaw3A4fyJ-0UUFYRmeWfjgUAX

I dont fully understand your objection, and I think they agree that axiom 5 is one of the faulty steps, but anyways these papers seem like a good place to start. Pretty deep stuff!

Comment: Thanks for the papers, and, in fact, I have already come across both of them several times before. However, what is it that you don't understand about my objection? I even provided an example to explain what I mean. What exactly is not clear?